# Regex to remove version history numbering from end of file names

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to regex and I'm trying to write an expression to remove version history numbering from the end of a big group of file names for use in File Renamer.
These are the various forms of version history I am trying to remove:

```
1.0 2.1a 3.5b v4.6 v5.7a v6.8b V7.9 V8.0a V9.1b And any of the previous forms 
can be enclosed in () [] or {} Maximum 5 Character + 2 brackets.
```

Examples followed by the desired result:

```
File-Name(v1.0).txt - File-Name.txt
fn1[V1.1].txt - fn1.txt 
FN2(v1.2a).txt -  FN2.txt
filename1.3.txt - filename.txt
file(name)1.4b.txt - file(name).txt
[file]name-V1.5.txt - [file]name-.txt
Author - [book 01](1.6).txt - Author - [book 01].txt
```

This is the expression I've written to remove them:

```
\s?([\[\(\{]?[vV]?[1-9]\.[0-9][ab]?[\]\)\}]?)\.txt 
REPLACE: .txt
```

I do not want it to remove anything larger than 5 characters in brackets, for example:

```
Author - [Book 1.0].txt
```

Should NOT be changed.

I want to make the closing brackets conditional on the presence of the opening bracket in a position where they can contain a maximum of 5 characters, which must include a "."
between two numbers.

Other examples of edge cases it must ignore:

```
FN-volume1.txt 
FN[Vol3.0].txt
FileName - book 2.txt
```

EDIT: Eventually got it to work in JS by removing the < symbol:

```
s?([\[({][vV]?\d+\.\d+[ab]?[\])}]|(?!([\[({]))[vV]?\d+\.\d+[ab]?(?![\])}]))(?=\W?\.\w{3})
```

Comment: So the output of the failing example should be `Author - [Book].txt`?

Comment: What regex engine are you using? Some engines include a special conditional syntax.

Comment: @Bohemian, Sorry I see I could have been clearer on that. "The Author - [Book 1.0].txt" should be completely ignored. I am only trying to remove file version history numbering where present, not book series or volume numbers. I want the brackets to contain the maximum of 5 characters including the '.' and no spaces. Some do have mismatched types of brackets so that it OK. The closing bracket should be conditional on the opening bracket at the beggining of the maximum 5 character code.

Comment: @Kendall Frey, Not sure, I'm using Sherrod Computers, File Renamer 6.0.1 but cant seem to find what it's using.

Comment: @zarnia the best way to convey your idea is to provide examples of edge cases and what part of them (if anything) you want matched. We can then use your examples to test our regexes to assert they match correctly for all test cases. Can you edit your question to add edge case examples?

Comment: @Bohemian, I've edited my original post to try and make it as clear as I can. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, that's clear now. I have altered the regex as brackets must be both there or both absent.

Comment: @Bohemian, That expression cause File Renamer to freeze. Any of the PHP, JS, or PY expressions from here usually work OK on it:  http://regex101.com/r/jU1pD3/1

Comment: @Bohemian, File Renamer must be using JS, the Lookbehind isn't supported: http://regex101.com/r/jU1pD3/2 is there another way to do that in JS? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alternation that first tries to match *with both* brackets, then *without* brackets (using negative look arounds) effectively making the *pair* optional - ie both there or both absent:

```
\s?([\[({][vV]?\d+\.\d+[ab]?[\])}]|(?<![\[({])[vV]?\d+\.\d+[ab]?(?![\])}]))(?=\W?\.\w{3})
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/KDfYm94sLh)

This regex matches just the version, so replace with blank.

I have also made the file extension flexible - all file types ae handled (if this is unwanted, replace `\w{3}` with `txt`).

The regex for the version number has been simplified, and unnecessary escaping in character classes removed.

Also note that your approach is slightly naive as bracket types don't have to match, eg `(v1.2]` would match. If that's not a possibility, don't worry, but if it is, you would need a separate alternation for each bracket type pair.